# Nginx doesn't work on my VPS

Tags: nginx, nodejs

The first idea was to set up a Node.js server on my VPS so I followed this article: [Setup node js in production](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

However in this article it is advised to use this command:
`sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/local/bin/node` in order to ensure my node app can be accessible without providing 3000 port after the url.

Then I moved on to this article [Installing nginx on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin) to allow multiple hosts accessing different apps on my server. When I install nginx and try running the address it should display Welcome to nginx page. However it still points to the node app I've got running using pm2 package. I have a suspicion that it is due to the setcap I've done in the first article. Can anyone tell me how to reverse this setcap command so I can continue setting up nginx?

Comment: In web browsers if a port is not specified after the host in a url, it defaults to 80, You can't have more that one service listening on a given port. Your node app is running on port 80, so nginx can't bind to that port. It could have been the other way around. nginx running but not your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're still running NodeJS on port 80. You can only run one thing on a port at a time. You need to:

- Shift this node application back to a high port. That means changing your `.listen(80, ...)` to `.listen(8000, ...)` or some other port.
- Have Nginx reverse-proxy back to that port:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
  }
  ```

What you did with `setcap` doesn't *need* to be reversed. It's not what is blocking nginx from loading on port 80.

Comment: The PM2 was running on that port and that's why it didn't allow the nginx, thanks very much!